# Implementing a protocol from another namespace with defrecord

Tags: clojure, nullpointerexception, protocols, record

I'm trying to get a Clojure record to implement a protocol from another namespace using the defrecord syntax, however calling "satisfies?" gives a null pointer exception. The code compiles and I can call the protocol's methods on record instances successfully, only I can't get "satisfies?" to work. I've tried using "extend" instead of implementing the protocol within the defrecord syntax and got the same problem.

The record (in a namespace which imports the protocol):

```clj
(defrecord LoxFunction [declaration]
  LoxCallable
  (arity [this] (count (:params declaration)))
  (call [this _ arguments]
    (let [env (env/new-environment @globals)
          env-with-params
          (reduce
           (fn [env [param argument]]
             (env/define-pure env (:lexeme param) argument))
           env
           (map vector (:params declaration) arguments))]
      (execute-block (:body declaration) env-with-params)))
  Object
  (toString [this]
    (str "<fn " (-> declaration :name :lexeme) ">")))
```

and the protocol in another namespace:

```clj
(defprotocol LoxCallable
  (arity [this])
  (call [this interpreter-variables arguments]))
```

The error when calling "satisfies" on a record invocation is:

```
      Execution error (NullPointerException) at interpr.interpreter/eval17428$fn (interpreter.clj:164).

              core.clj:  144  clojure.core/instance?
      core_deftype.clj:  536  clojure.core/find-protocol-impl
      core_deftype.clj:  569  clojure.core/satisfies?
      core_deftype.clj:  569  clojure.core/satisfies?
       interpreter.clj:  164  interpr.interpreter/eval17428/fn
          MultiFn.java:  229  clojure.lang.MultiFn/invoke
       interpreter.clj:  176  interpr.interpreter/eval17432/fn
          MultiFn.java:  229  clojure.lang.MultiFn/invoke
       interpreter.clj:  203  interpr.interpreter/eval17457/fn
          MultiFn.java:  229  clojure.lang.MultiFn/invoke
       interpreter.clj:  266  interpr.interpreter/interpret
       interpreter.clj:  261  interpr.interpreter/interpret
              core.clj:   15  interpr.core/run
              core.clj:    9  interpr.core/run
                  REPL:   91  interpr.core/eval17499
```

...and so on.

Edit: the code calling satisfies? is:

```clj
(defmethod evaluate Call [expr]
  (let [callee (evaluate (:callee expr))
        arguments (map evaluate (:arguments expr))]
    (cond
      (not (satisfies? LoxCallable callee))
      (throw (error/runtime-error "Can only call functions and classes." (:paren expr)))

      (not (= (count arguments) (arity callee)))
      (throw (error/runtime-error (:paren expr)
                            (str "Expected " (arity callee) " arguments but got " (count arguments) ".")))

      :else
      (call callee interpreter arguments))))
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show the code that calls `(satisifies?)` ?
The NPE in `instance?` means that the object passsed in is `nil`.

Comment: I've added the code that calls satisfies? to my post now. I also made sure when I was trying to fix this that "callee" is not nil and is actually an instance of the LoxFunction record.

Comment: That error would show up if `LoxCallable` somehow got redefined to a nil value (not the object).  For example: `(satisfies? nil 1)`.  Perhaps you overrode the definition somehow?